# How do I add a caption to an image in Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs

When inserting an image into a Google Document, text can be made to wrap around the image by clicking on it and choosing the "Wrap Text" option.  How can I also add a caption to the image, with text still wrapped around the image and caption?

Comment: Since all the answers suggest using Drawings, note that they are not included when you download the file as `.docx` :(

Comment: Try captionizer add-on. To use it select image and go to `Add-ons > Captionizer > Images > Number selected image`.

Comment: The [Caption Maker plugin](https://www.zsucic.com/captionmaker) can create captions for figures and tables including numbering and listing them.

Comment: Don't have the rep to answer this but I've found a workable solution in `format > columns` .. can be a bit fiddly with edits, etc. but lets you retain full quality images (and editable captions) separated from the flow of the doc (without breaking the flow). Add your text content followed by your inline images, split into two columns, add as many newlines as you need (shared between / after your text content & last caption) so your images appear in a single column.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As of October 25, 2013, Google Documents does not support text wrapping around tables, so inserting a table and putting an image and a caption in it will work but cannot be made to have text wrapped around it.

One workaround is that since text can wrap around images, we can choose Insert > Drawing... and create a drawing with the text we want to caption the image with.  The resulting drawing can be changed to have text wrapped around it, and can then be placed beneath the image we inserted.

**Here is a short gif showing the process:**

[image]

Comment: OP said nothing about tables

Comment: He is the OP, and tables are a suggested work around.

Comment: This appears to sadly be still true as of Nov 2016. Come on, Google!

Comment: 2018 - still true

Comment: 2019 - still true

Comment: 2020 - still true

Comment: 2020 - still true

Comment: 1992 - I was adding image captions in MS Word 2.0

Comment: 2021 - still true

Comment: May 2021 - still true. Google docs is the worst when it comes to report writing. Overleaf for the win!

Answer (score 23):

1. Choose Menu -> **Insert** -> **Drawing.**
2. Drag/Drop, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> or right-click and **paste in your image**.
3. **Click the "Textbox" button** near the top.
4. **Draw the textbox** underneath your image, add some text.
5. Set the lettering font/format with the "more" button upper left.

Comment: Which one is the "Textbox" button? Does this still exist?

Comment: That blurs the images too much. You can add the image to the document and then put the caption in as a drawing.

Comment: @user73457 Yeah. Google Docs is still super limited. If you download as docx, for example, you get the caption as textbox, unformated. So some editing will still be needed. But if you download as pdf, then it is blurred as hell.

Comment: There is no textbox button. You can't float images, you can't caption images. It gives you an inline or wrap option (as if anything other than inline is available anyway), but no free placement option. "Super limited" is putting it lightly.

Answer (score 4):

You can paste the image into Insert>Drawing, and then add a textbox underneath it and save that. However, there is no way of automatically captioning an image, which I think is a problem that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by using  the Insert -> Drawing option.
Here is a guide on how to do add a caption and wrap text around an image or a table: https://web.archive.org/web/20141013025810/http://chromebookandroidnews.wordpress.com:80/2014/09/08/how-to-caption-and-wrap-text-around-images-or-tables-in-google-docs/

Comment: The site no longer exists. Do you remember the instructions?

Answer (score 1):

You can put in a text box in if you insert the image as a drawing.