# Automatic image numbering in Google Documents

Tags: google-docs

I have a Google Document in which I insert several images. Underneath each images, there is this a caption: *Image 7: some description*.

I'd like the image number to increment automatically on the document. So that if I rearrange the structure it knows which number to give. Like it would do for notes.

I also need this feature for some requirements labeled : *R023: its description*. I'd like 23 to be an incremental variable too.

How can I achieve that? Do you know a plugin?

Comment: That's going to be hard. Does Google Documents even have a way to specify image captions? [Doesn't seem so](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51142/how-do-i-add-a-caption-to-an-image-in-google-documents).

Comment: I want this functionality not only for images anyway.

Comment: Ok, so you just need the numbering, then. Someone might be able to write a script for that.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Any docs for writing this kind of script ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs

Answer (score -2):

use Docx2Latex addon, Goto C-REF, add figure Caption and you can refer it any time,